# check into html code for a iframe inside custom tags

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, iframe

I am trying to get a text inside a tag in a html of an iframe inside another custom tag.

[image]

For example, as shown in the pic, the force-record-layout-section is a custom tag inside a div and there is a iframe that I am trying to get element from.

But it seems when the iframe is inside the custom tag, neither jquery nor Document.GetElementsById/Name/Class/Tag are returns anything instead , all returned undefined.

var frame =  document.getElementById("matchClassicStyleText");

console.log("iframe "+frame);

It just logged iframe undefined in the console.

When using jquery, it can locate the custom tag, but .html() returned empty.

Please help me understand if anything I have done wrong or there is other workaround.

The iframe
`<iframe force-alohapage_alohapage="" height="220px" width="100%" scrolling="yes" allowtransparency="true" name="vfFrameId_1641796894366" title="accessibility title" allowfullscreen="true" lang="en-US" allow="geolocation *; microphone *; camera *" tabindex="0"></iframe>`

Tried document.getElementsByName("vfFrameId_1641796894366") and it is also not working.

matchClassicStyleText is one of the div inside the loaded html of the iframe.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the iFrame from the same  origin as the page with your script?
I cannot see any ID on your iFrame in your image. We do prefer HTML to images of HTML

Comment: Thanks. I am using tampermonkey to grab some texts from the page.  The iFrame is inside the same origin page where I am running the tampermonkey.

Comment: Try `document.querySelector("[force-alohapage_alohapage]")`

Comment: Thanks. document.getElementsByName("vfFrameId_1641796894366")[0] logged with    iframe undefined.

Comment: var frame =  document.querySelector("[force-alohapage_alohapage]");

  console.log("iframe "+frame); 

Also logged iframe undefined... Is this because of the external custom tag? so it is not able to locate the iframe correctly?  Thanks again.

Comment: What does `console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].name)` say if you paste it into the console

Comment: It returns 
document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].name
>'sfdcSoftphone'.

Comment: Seems to NOT be the iFrame you expect. So try `[...document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")].forEach((ifr,i) => console.log(i,ifr.name))`

Comment: Not sure why, only 0 'sfdcSoftphone' returned in the loop. And I can see there are 5 results if I search "<iframe" in the elements of the chrome debug tools.

Comment: This is the first iframe in the search results for "<iframe"
<iframe frameborder="0" allow="camera *; geolocation *; microphone *; autoplay *" src="https://apps.xxxmaskedxxx" width="100%" name="sfdcSoftphone" height="100%" tabindex="0" title="PureConnect for Salesforce Lightning" data-aura-rendered-by="759:0" class="openctiSoftPhone" data-aura-class="openctiSoftPhone"></iframe>

The one I am locating is the 2nd result.

Comment: Again, the one with name "sfdcSoftphone" looks much outer layer than the rest of the iframes. Others are wrapped by nested custom tags.

Comment: Maybe the custom tag as a shadow dom ? Have you tried "document.queryselector['force-aloha-page'].shadowRoot.queryselector['iframe'];"

Comment: console.log(document.queryselector['force-aloha-page'].shadowRoot.queryselector['iframe']);
xxx:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'force-aloha-page')
    at <anonymous>:1:35  Any Typo?

Comment: try console.log(document.queryselector['force-aloha-page'].shadowRoot) if it's null then either there's no shadow dom or it is closed and you can't access it.

Comment: console.log(document.queryselector['force-aloha-page'].shadowRoot)
VM43604:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'force-aloha-page')
    at <anonymous>:1:35
(anonymous) @ VM43604:1   thanks. It returned undefined.

Comment: i didn't realize but you might have nested shadow dom. you should try accessing "shadowRoot" on the first custom element and make your way down from there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240917/discussion-between-jepsenwan-and-neokyr).